# How can a DNS server change user's IP?

Tags: vpn, dns, tunnel, ipv4

For example User A's WAN IP is 2.2.2.2, When the user sets up this particular DNS server in his router or inside his operating system's IPv4 settings, his WAN IP will change to something else for example 3.3.3.3.

How is this possible?

And for security reasons, I think this will make the clients safer as it works like a VPN.

The only issue I see with it is that, if two users that are using this DNS and access a same website, they will show in the same IP, so admins of that website could think they are double accounting and could potentially ban them.

Comment: The IP address will never change, because you configured DNS. However it may change for no reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is this possible?

It isn't.

---

Okay, it is somewhat possible, but it's not nearly as good an idea as it sounds.

The DNS server only tells clients where their real destination is – it doesn't actually transport the data packets, so it has no way of altering them. (The client can even use completely different Internet links for DNS requests and real data connections.)

To achieve what you want, the DNS server would need to provide fake responses that always point at a relay server as the destination (and hope that clients don't reject these responses as obviously fake due to DNSSEC verification failures). That relay server would need to act as a "transparent proxy", accepting all connections, reading the handshake, then making new connections to the real destination and relaying the data. (There already is software for doing this, though it's aimed at proxying connections from a single LAN.)

The relay server doesn't have any general way of knowing which TCP connection or which UDP datagram corresponds to which original domain. This can only be done with a few specific protocols such as HTTP or TLS (HTTPS, SMTPS, IMAPS, FTPS), which include the domain as part of the initial handshake.

> And for security reasons, I think this will make the clients safer as it works like a VPN.

Only for requests which actually involve DNS – it cannot do anything for "direct" IP connections, e.g. when a game gets server IP addresses from the login server, or when a BitTorrent client gets peer IP addresses from a tracker. Those would completely bypass your system.

Also, only for the few previously mentioned protocols which send the hostname in the initial handshake. Your clients would be completely unable to use any other protocol – almost no games, no VoIP, no SSH, no BitTorrent, and mostly no actual VPNs.

Also, only if the clients *disable* the security feature known as "DNSSEC" and trust you with deliberately providing fake information to all their DNS queries.

Also, **it cannot provide packet encryption** (nor even integrity protection), which is one of the main selling points of a VPN! For many users, it's where most of the 'safety' comes from.

(Besides, many client IPv4 addresses are already dynamic and/or shared; the need to hide them is rather low on the priority list.)

So no, it doesn't act like a VPN.

Comment: I don't think the DNS server is providing fake IPs, because I've checked with `nslookup` and compared them to what another DNS server was telling. And since this IP changing feature of the DNS I'm talking about, also works with HTTPS and the green icon with a lock shows on my browser, I don't think it's trying to change certificates, so I love your idea about transparent proxy. Also I haven't done anything to my system that would disable DNSSEC. I didn't even know it existed.

Comment: @Shayan: If the DNS responses are identical, then either a) the proxying is not related to the DNS server at all, or b) the network you're on is intercepting _all_ DNS queries, not only those sent to this server, but also those sent to legitimate public servers. Both variants are common in "captive portal" networks, and both cannot be done with pure DNS – they require rerouting at the client's network.

Comment: I've been searching a lot but I still can't find the software you mentioned, that proxies connections on LAN using DNS, do you recall it's name? Also does this whole thing come with a fancy name where I can read on more about? Thanks very much @grawity

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a DNS Server, you should be looking at setting up a
[Proxy Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server):

> a proxy server is a server (a computer system or an application) that acts as an intermediary for requests from clients seeking resources from other servers

A proxy then lets you go online under a different IP address identity,
which is the IP address of the proxy itself.

Every client that uses the proxy is a different connection, so many persons
can use the proxy, seeming all to have the same IP address, without any problem.